# My Navigation Drawer just doesn't works. I have created the screens and gone through a lot of examples

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation-drawer, flutter-web

My drawer is not navigating to other screens. I don't know why, I have gone through a lot of StackOverflow solutions.
I have created routes also but it is still not working.

Here is my code for the drawer.

```
class SideDrawer extends StatelessWidget{
  const SideDrawer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: [
          const DrawerHeader(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
            ),
            child: Text('Welcome!'),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('Home'),
            onTap: () => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Routes.home)
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('Settings'),
            onTap: () => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Routes.settings)
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('LogOut'),
            onTap: () => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Routes.logout)
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  
}
```

Here is the routes class.

```
import 'package:adaptive_layout/widgets/candidate_form.dart';
import 'package:adaptive_layout/widgets/logout.dart';
import 'package:adaptive_layout/widgets/settings.dart';

class Routes {
  static const String home = CandidateForm.routeName;
  static const String settings = Settings.routeName;
  static const String logout = LogOut.routeName;
}
```

All the classes just have a text displayer in the centre.
But neither the drawer closes on its own after onTap nor does it take to that page.

This is my MaterialAppWidget i.e. the main.dart.

```
import 'package:adaptive_layout/pages/desktop_page.dart';
import 'package:adaptive_layout/pages/mobile_page.dart';
import 'package:adaptive_layout/pages/tablet_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Views',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: SafeArea(
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            if(constraints.maxWidth < 600){
              return const MobilePage();
            }
            else if(constraints.maxWidth < 768){
              return const TabletPage();
            }
            else{
              return const DesktopPage();
            } 
          }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please help. being trying it for 2 days now.

Comment: show us your MaterialApp widget. If you want to use named routes you must set them there

Comment: I have updated the code in the question. Can you please check?

Comment: that's it, this is the problem... I'll write an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're not defining your routes in the `MaterialApp` widget. This is not necessary if you're using annonymous routes, but it is a **must** if you're using **named** routes.

You'll need to get rid of you're `home:` property on the `MaterialApp` and move your `LayoutBuilder` elsewhere.

Like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Views',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        // Here you define the names and the Widgets (Preferably ones with a Scaffold) that are your pages
        '/': (context) => const HomePage(),
        '/second': (context) => const SecondScreen(),
       },
    );
  }
}
```

Then to navigate to them using named Routes:

```
() => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/second')
```

If you want more info, there's a [cookbock](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes) on the Flutter website that show you how to use it.